# rails devise sign_in doesn't work on redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, signing

I have this method:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        if params[:mypmnode]
          session[:return_to] = projects_pmnode_path(params[:mypmnode])
          sign_in(@user)
        end
        format.html { redirect_to(session[:return_to], :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        @create_company = true if params[:user][:company_id].blank? and  params[:user][:company_attributes].length > 0
        @create_department = true if params[:user][:department_id].blank? and  params[:user][:department_attributes].length > 0
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The idea is that if the user is updated, He is automatically signed-in and redirected to a page where authentication is required.

In this page, I have: before_filter :authenticate_user!

This doesn't work on redirect.

If I then go to another page making use of this sign_in function, then the user logs-in correctly.

Any idea why redirect doesn't work? Thx!

UPDATE:

to make it clearer, I insert the second page code (controller):

```
class PmnodesController < Projects::BaseController

  before_filter authenticate_user!

  def index
    @pmnodes = Pmnode.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
    end
  end
```

Comment: you mean user should redirect to login(sign_in) page after updating attributes?

Comment: No, I'm trying to have him signed-in automatically and then redirect him to a private page without having to sign-in manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the password is updated on @user, devise will invalidate the session. After the update_attributes, you could try calling `sign_out` first.

```
sign_out(@user)
sign_in(@user)
```

Comment: This also worked for me. As an admin I wanted to sign in as another user, but first I had to sign_out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your progam goes inside this blog

```
if params[:mypmnode]
      session[:return_to] = projects_pmnode_path(params[:mypmnode])
      sign_in(@user)
end
```

if not this should sign in your use automatically.

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    if params[:mypmnode]
      session[:return_to] = projects_pmnode_path(params[:mypmnode])

    end
    sign_in(@user)

    format.html { redirect_to(session[:return_to], :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    @create_company = true if params[:user][:company_id].blank? and  params[:user][:company_attributes].length > 0
    @create_department = true if params[:user][:department_id].blank? and  params[:user][:department_attributes].length > 0
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I'm positive! The redirect goes to the right page. I think that current_user is not redefined properly after updating the record. I update the password, so if authenticate_user! uses an old password value, it could be the reason for the problem. But I don't know how to force the update of current_user

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

I had a controller method that created and signed in a user

```
def new
  @user = User.create!
  sign_in @user
  redirect_to some_nondefault_path
end
```

where some_nondefault_path required authentication. The `new` action did not require authentication. The user was getting created and signed in, but the user session wasn't persisting and the user was getting 401-unauthorized and redirected to the signin page instead of some_nondefault_path.

I ended up solving it by adding

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :new
```

to the first controller. It seemed to be trying to verify the CSRF token before creating the user session, which was failing and blocking the creation of a normal user session (even though it wasn't trying to `authenticate_user!`).

Hope this helps!